# Function doesnt accept a parameter

Tags: wpf, powershell

I have a Powershell/WPF project. Function below creates and adds a TreeViewItem to my TreeView, and returns that TreeViewItem to the caller. If adding to TreeView's root level - it works fine. But when I try to create a new TreeViewItem for the one returned previously - it fails, saying

> Create-TreeViewItem : Cannot process argument transformation on
> parameter 'parent'. Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type
> "System.Object[]" to type "System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem". At
> C:\Users...\View\MyView.xaml.ps1:86
> char:26
> Create-TreeViewItem $item1 "11" "A" $false
> CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Create-TreeViewItem], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Create-TreeViewItem

That is, TreeViewItem created by my function, is not accepted by same function as a TreeViewItem. How can this happen? My function  is:

```
function Create-TreeViewItem([System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem]$parent, $pk, $text, $isChecked)
{
    $treeviewitem = [System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem]::new(); # Bears own PK
    $textblock = [Windows.Controls.TextBlock]::new();

    $textblock.Text = $pk + "   " + $text

    $treeviewitem.Header = $textblock

    if($null -eq $parent)
    {
        $accountsTree.Items.Add($treeviewitem)
    }
    else
    {
        $parent.Items.Add($treeviewitem)
    }

    return $treeviewitem
}
```

Called by:

```
$btOk.Add_Click(
{
    $item1 = Create-TreeViewItem $null "1" "One" $false
    $item2 = Create-TreeViewItem $null "2" "Two" $false

    # FAILS HERE
    Create-TreeViewItem $item1 "11" "A" $false
    Create-TreeViewItem $item2 "22" "A" $false
})
```

Comment: What is `$accountsTree` ?

Comment: I guess you should leave out the type definition in parameter `$parent` so its value can be $null.

Comment: Your `.Items.Add()` calls have a return value (of type `[int]`) that _implicitly_  becomes part of your function's output, so that it returns _two_ objects, which are captured as a `System.Object[]` array. To prevent that, use `$null = ....` See the accepted answer to the linked duplicate for details (the question is different, from yours but the problem is ultimately the same).

Comment: To spell it out: use `$null = $accountsTree.Items.Add($treeviewitem)` and `$null = $parent.Items.Add($treeviewitem)`

Comment: Glad to hear it.